# Why is this PDF metadata not valid?

Tags: pdf, text, pdf-generation

I need help understanding how to make this document compliant.
Any other advice would be wonderful.

I have been digging through the various examples, tutorials, and official documents; and I think I am close to the solution.

The "hello world" text appears in the MediaBox, but metadata is inaccessible.

The rules seem clear, but things like Title do not appear for pdfinfo or File>Properties.

```
%PDF-1.1
¥±˫

% Metadata (referenced by trailer /Info)
0 0 obj
  /Title        (simple 80x25 text PDF)
  /Subject      (test PDF)
  /Producer     (simple.80x25.text.PDF.py)
  /Creator      (gvim)
  /Keywords     (PDF test)
  /CreationDate (D:2018021300000-05'00')
endobj

% Content (referenced by trailer /Root)
1 0 obj
  <<
    /Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R
  >>
endobj

% Text display box (referenced by 1 0 obj)
2 0 obj
  << /Type /Pages /Kids [3 0 R] /Count 1 /MediaBox [0 0 480 300] >>
endobj

% Text font (referenced by 2 0 obj)
3 0 obj
  << /Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /Resources
    << /Font
      << /F1
        << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /BaseFont /Courier >>
      >>
    >>
    /Contents 4 0 R
  >>
endobj

% Text to be displayed in the box (referenced by 3 0 obj)
4 0 obj
  << /Length 5 0 R >>
stream
  BT
    /F1 10 Tf 12 TL 0 290 Td
    (hello world) Tj
  ET
endstream
endobj

% Main (collect resources for reference from entrypoint)
trailer
  << /Root 1 0 R /Info 0 0 R /Size 6 >>

startxref 0
%%EOF
```

Comment: There are no `xrefs` in your document, so not one object can be located. If this text dump is different from the actual PDF, post it online somewhere and add a link.

Comment: .. that minimal (well, not-existing) `xref` table is probably reconstructed by Acrobat Reader, as it asks to *save* the PDF after opening. That is a strong indication it found something to "repair".

Comment: This is entirely hand-written.  It is not a dump.  I don't understand the use of xrefs yet.  If xrefs are to be added, I will have to calculate the values.  I have not found documentation for the xref formula.  But I really don't understand how xrefs will fix the problem.  Please explain.

Comment: From the PDF reference on `startxref`: "Following this line are the cross-reference entries themselves, one per line. Each entry shall be exactly 20 bytes long, including the end-of-line marker [..] where nnnnnnnnnn shall be a 10-digit byte offset in the decoded stream". These point to the start of each object. BTW the first entry `0 0 obj` is *reserved*. Are you sure you are following the specs correctly?

Comment: I will change the 0 0 obj to a better one (I didn't see the reserved).  I do not understand the role of xrefs.  I assumed they were for navigation through the document, and there is no navigation needed for this document.  Can you explain what xrefs do so that I can insert a proper one?

Comment: I can but why not check the [official specifications](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)? That's where my quoted text comes from. (There is lots more of it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with 1 for document information and put the keys in a dictionary object, your sample is missing the << and >>:

```
% Metadata (referenced by trailer /Info)

1 0 obj
<<
  /Title        (simple 80x25 text PDF)
  /Subject      (test PDF)
  /Producer     (simple.80x25.text.PDF.py)
  /Creator      (gvim)
  /Keywords     (PDF test)
  /CreationDate (D:2018021300000-05'00')
>>
endobj
```

Comment: PERFECT!  Thank you.  Missing << >> was the problem.
I will still try to get a handle on xrefs, but now I can defer that.